# Can I use Db context inside an HttpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest, authorization, httpmodule

I have to implement **HttpModule** for a condition which should return http status **401** if condition get failed before request hits the controller. In this condition i need to access database to compare some values, My question is, Is it a good practice to use dbcontext inside the HttpModule implementation? or there are any other ways to achieve the same.

**NOTE:** I know the same can be done through the Custom Authorize attribute, but for that i need to change in lot of places.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we have a base controller in all our applications and that will be handling all the filtering and condition checking based on the request url, role and some more conditions, if all meets only the url redirection will perform and the request will hit the actual controller.

My suggestion is to have some kind of mechanism to keep base controller or some OOP approach in all your controllers, that will be much easier when you want to modify something which are common behavior